# How to modify a value in a property file, when key-value is fetched by a lib class?

Tags: java, spring, properties-file

So i have a properties file, where the current env is passed as a value to the `spring.profiles.active` property. I need this value to be a edited such that all the hyphens are changed to underscore. I cannot make changes in the Java code.

I tried using SpEL, but it wasn't helpful.

`spring.profiles.active=${oauth2.env}`

**actual**: `spring.profiles.active=prflv-ssz`
**expected**: `spring.profiles.active=prflv_ssz`

Answer (score 0):

You could call static methods to do this (e.g. String.replace() ), see https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#expressions-beandef-xml-based